# Pascal compilation error

Tags: pascal

This is the code:

```
program pi18;
var 
  a,b,c,P:real;
begin
  read(a,b,c);
  if(a+b<c) or (b+c<a) or (a+c<b) then
    writeln('Nu exista asa triunghi')
  else
  begin
    P:=a+b+c;
    if(a=b) and (a=c) then 
      write('Triunghiul este echil')
    else
     if(sqr(a) = sqr(b) + sqr(c)) or (sqr(b) = sqr(a) + sqr(c)) or (sqr(c) = sqr(a) + sqr(b)) then
      write('Triunghiul este dreptunghic'); readln();
    else
      write('Triunghiul este arbitrar'); readln();
  end;
  writeln('Perimetrul este: ', P);
end.
```

And I have this error:

> Syntax error, ";" expected but "ELSE" found

This code is for:
- says the perimeter of a triangle.
- compare if the a,b,c are numbers for some types of triangles.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: @Mahonri Looks like it needs one more edit now ;-)

Comment: So, anyone can help me?

Comment: _@xQ_ Sure: Use braces `{}`

Comment: It's pascal :), no need for {}

Comment: The error speaks for itself. Have you tried to fix the code this error refers to?

Comment: @xQxQx `begin` `end` then? Here in particular: `write('Triunghiul este dreptunghic'); readln();`

Comment: `write('Triunghiul este dreptunghic'); readln();` needs to be surrounded by `begin` .. `end`

Comment: Why the downvotes??

Comment: @MK. , look down and please answer, I need to fix this in ~25 minutes... :(

Comment: @xQxQx: I know that those 25 minutes have passed by now. But this is not a quick-answer service for homework. Fact is that you should read up on "compound statements" in Pascal.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute multiple statements when a condition is true, you need to wrap them with `begin` and `end`. Putting them on the same line doesn't automatically group them. So you need `begin` and `end` around:

```
write('Triunghiul este dreptunghic'); readln();
```

and

```
write('Triunghiul este arbitrar'); readln();
```

Since you didn't do this, it just processes the first statement as the `if` block. When it sees the `else` statement, it reports an error because there's no preceding `if` statement to match it with.

Comment: And also the appearance of a ; (or not) before an ELSE has special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

In Pascal if you have multiple statements between then and else you still need to put begin and end around them:

```
if(sqr(a) = sqr(b) + sqr(c)) or (sqr(b) = sqr(a) + sqr(c)) or (sqr(c) = sqr(a) + sqr(b)) then
begin
  write('Triunghiul este dreptunghic'); 
  readln();
end
else
```

Comment: He also needs to group the statements after `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code lacks `begin`-`end` around the multiple statements following `if`:

```
if(a=b) and (a=c) then 
  write('Triunghiul este echil') // single statement, no begin-end required (but possible)
else if(sqr(a) = sqr(b) + sqr(c)) or (sqr(b) = sqr(a) + sqr(c)) or (sqr(c) = sqr(a) + sqr(b)) then
begin 
  write('Triunghiul este dreptunghic'); 
  readln();
end
else
begin
  write('Triunghiul este arbitrar'); 
  readln();
end;
```

To make this more consistent, I would even do:

```
if(a=b) and (a=c) then 
begin
  write('Triunghiul este echil')
end
else etc...
```